# sql semi join optimize

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, semi-join

there are two tables

```
t1 { id, name, ...}

t2 { t1_id , date_time, parameter, value, ...}
```

t1 and t2 are oracle partitioned table. t2 is large.

i want to fetch t1 which matches a time range from t2 :

```
select id, name, ... from t1 partition(t1_partition_name) 
where t1.id in( select distinct t1_id from t2 partition(t2_partition_name) 
             where date_time > to_date('20120627 00','YYYYMMDD HH24') 
                   and date_time <to_date('20120627 12','YYYYMMDD HH24')
          )
```

the sub query would return about 10K t1_id.
it is really slow, any suggestion?

Comment: What's your partition scheme on both tables and do you have any index (global/local)? What's the data volume (cardinality, size of rows)?

Comment: Remove `distinct`. It uses hash to do the join? Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: Execution plans would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT id, name, ... 
  FROM t1 partition(t1_partition_name) aa
 WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT * 
       FROM t2 partition(t2_partition_name) ex
      WHERE ex.t1_id = aa.id
        AND ex.date_time > to_date('20120627 00','YYYYMMDD HH24') 
        AND ex.date_time <to_date('20120627 12','YYYYMMDD HH24' )
     )
  ;
```

BTW I Don't know anything about Oracle's partition sub-syntax. I expect that the partition(tx_partition_name) can be removed completely, since the DBMS should already know this. It also collides with the "PARTITION BY" phrase.

Comment: I think the Exists are equal to in clause in oracle. but I'll have a try, thx.

Comment: No, there is a difference WRT NULLs. (depending on the NULLability of the things being compared. Normally, they would be PK+FK, and thus (probably) NOT NULL. Three-valued logic can cause a lot of gotchas) I don't know oracle, but a 'defensive' optimiser will be very careful wrt "shuffling around" nullable/not nullable terms in the query plan.